# Как правильно создать дочернюю тему Вордпресс от родительской, если в themes лежат только блоки родительской?

Tags: wordpress

Как правильно создать дочернюю тему Вордпресс от родительской, если в themes лежат только блоки родительской?
Новичок я  в Вордпрессе.
Задача: создать дочернюю тему от родительской, чтобы внести изменения.
Читаю, как создать дочернюю тему. Везде пишут, что нужно зайти в themes, в ней есть каталог родительской темы, рядом с ним создать каталог дочерней темы. 
У меня родительская тема не вынесена в отдельный каталог.
Можно ли её вынести в отдельный каталог и рядом с ней создать дочернюю?
В таком случае, на что и где нужно смотреть, чтобы, например, поправить пути и всё работало? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы точно в том месте смотрите? Что-то на структуру WP вообще не похожа, даже если так смотреть, то в этой теме нет минимальных файлов для работы style.css и index.php

Comment: И правда это не вордпресс)))

Comment: Хотя админка на вордпрессе.
Скрипты подключены через wp-content. А в комментариях .php - диафан смс. Похоже и структура от него.

Comment: Я конечно многое видел, но чтобы интегрировать одну CMS в другую это как-то странно. Мне кажется вы что-то путаете и не в том каталоге смотрите. В самой админке WP какие темы подключены (внешний вид->темы)? Ищите на хостинге папки wp-content/wp-admin

Comment: Ага. В другом каталоге искала. Нашла wp-admin и wp-content, и themes. Нашла нужную тему. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну а теперь делайте по инструкции в ответе ниже, или по [этой](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B)

Comment: В продолжении темы вопрос.
Стили дочерней темы не подключаются. При установке темы использовала плагин  https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator/
Знаю, что есть гугл и гора инфы в нём. Читаю, применяю, не помогает.

Comment: Вероятно, не туда и не так смотрю.
Куда правильно смотреть, чтоб получилось?

Comment: Никогда не использовал плагины для создания дочерних тем, не вижу в этом смысла. В любом случае, если хотите чтобы вам как-то помогли, то создайте отдельный вопрос, прикрепите скрины/код. Вслепую вам точно никто не поможет.

Answer (score 0):

> Как правильно создать дочернюю тему Вордпресс

Создать каталог и поместить в неё style.css с соответствующим заголовком.
Файл функций и [шаблоны](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2) - по мере надобности.
[Документация](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)

Но проще и лучше с пом. спец. плагинов. Напр https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator/

> на что и где нужно смотреть

На скрине не тема ВП.  Нет ни файла  стилей (самого главного файла темы) ни шаблонов. См [Анатомия Темы](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC#.D0.90.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.BC.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.A2.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.8B)